# mysql_connect error obsoleto

Tags: php, php7, php5

Realicé mi sitio, viendo tutoriales, de aquí de allá, quedo mi frankstein, pero ahora que necesito hacer cambios la versión de php ya no es compatible, no soy profesional, y aunque leí documentación, no tengo idea que hacer, realicé varios intentos, pero sin conocimiento, y no logro accesar, gracias.

```
<?php

$link=mysql_connect("localhost", "root","1234");


if(!$link){
    mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    mysqli_set_charset('utf-8', $link);
    
    die("Error de conexion" .mysql_error());
    
}

mysql_select_db("bdgb", $link) or die("Error al conectar con la base de datos". mysql_error());


function cerrarconexion(){
    mysql_close($GLOBALS['link']);
}


?>
```

Comment: Mil gracias A. Cedano!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas mesclando **mysql** con **mysqli**, debes hacerlo en una sola forma. Existen infinitos ejemplos de conexión en internet.

En mi caso, me gusta darles mi toque personal, y cuando hago un código puro tengo este script que funciona muy bien.

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'pruebas');

class DBM{

    // Para llamar al metodo privado conectar()
    public function conexion()
    {
        return self::conectar();
    }
    // Metodo privado donde hacemos la conexion a la DB
    private function conectar(){
        $MySQLi = $this->mysqli = new MySQLi (DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_DATABASE);

        if ($MySQLi->connect_errno){
            $debugger = '<b>Error al conectar al Servidor !!!<br>Error '.$MySQLi->connect_errno.':</b> '.$MySQLi->connect_error;
            echo $debugger;
            $error ='<br>
                    <div class="centrar" style="font-size:25px;">
                        <div class="label label-danger">
                            Error de Conexion, contacte con un Administrador !!!
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>';
            echo $error;
        }
        else{
            // Definimos el charset de la DataBase
            $MySQLi->set_charset('utf8');

            // DataBase connection info
            // var_dump($this->mysqli);

            $response = '';
            $response .= $this->mysqli->host_info . "<br>";
            $response .= 'Conectado al Servidor: <b>'.DB_HOST.'</b><br>';
            $response .= 'Base de Datos: <b>'.DB_DATABASE.'</b><br>';

            $response .= ('Conjunto de caracteres de la Base de Datos es: <b>'.$this->mysqli->character_set_name().'</b><br>');
            echo $response;
        }
    }

    // Metodo publico para desconectarnos
    public function desconectar(){
        $MySQLi = $this->mysqli;

        // Si hay una conexion, la cerramos
        if (isset($MySQLi)) {
            $cerrar = $MySQLi->close();
            // Destruimos la variable
            unset($MySQLi);
            if ($cerrar) {
                $response = '<hr>Conexion a la Base de Datos Cerrada !!!';
            }
            else{
                $response = '<hr>La Conexion a la Base de Datos sigue Abierta !!!';
            }
        }
        else{
            $response = '<hr>Conexion no esta definida';
        }
        echo $response;
    }
}

$dbm = new DBM();
$dbm->conexion();
$dbm->desconectar();
```

El resultado es el siguiente

[image: Conexión MySQL]

Tu puedes hacerlo de la manera que creas conveniente, pero puedes basarte en mi ejemplo para tener una referencia.

---

No olvides marcar la respuesta como **Aceptada** si resuelve tu problema/duda. :-)